# In ionic framework some of the <ion> tags not working

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm using Android Studio for Ionic projects... I'm new to Ionic, in my project none of the ion tags are working, CSS styles and classes are working...
, and so on are not working...
Can any one suggest me... where i did mistake...
Below is my code... In this code

```
<ion-view view-title="gayatri"></ion-view> this part wasn't working

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-      scalable=no, width=device-width">
 <title></title>

 <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
 <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
 -->

 <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

 <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>

 <!-- your app's js -->
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
 <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
  <h1 class="title">bar-dark</h1>
 </div>
 <ion-view view-title="gayatri"></ion-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using android studio?

Comment: yes you should use other simple text editor like sublime etc

Comment: oh really... sublime works for ionic...? is there any tutorial for sublime and inoic framework...? i didnt found any thing... can you provide me any link for this

Comment: Please, include the content of `js/app.js`.